# Wildcards for filter function in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using `dplyr` and I would like to filter my dataframe (biotypes) according to sample IDs which are the first column of the data frame, e.g. they look like this:

```
ID
chrX.tRNA494-SerAGA 
chrX.tRNA636-AlaCGC
mmu_piR_000007
...
```

I want to filter IDs starting with "chr" from IDs starting with "mmu":

```
biotype<- biotype %>% 
  filter( str_detect (biotype, "^chr") ==TRUE )
biotype
```

Can anyone help please? I am just looking for something like `*` that allows me to filter all rows that have a string starting with these particular characters ...

Comment: So your desired output would include `chrX.tRNA494-SerAGA` and `chrX.tRNA636-AlaCGC` but not include `mmu_piR_000007`?  Is that correct?  (It's always helpful to include example input and output in your question.)

Comment: Yes exactly. Sorry you are right I should have been more precise

Answer (score 6):

I think you were very close already.

```
library(stringr)
biotype %>% filter(str_detect(ID,"^chr"))
```

(you need to specify the column name, and `== TRUE` is superfluous).

Answer (score 3):

What about `grepl`?

```
biotype <- biotype %>%
    filter(grepl('^chr', ID))
```