# R Function to find corresponding patient IDs that have 'Bone' Entry?

Tags: r

I have a dataset and I used 'grep' to find how many entries had the word "bone" to represent how many patients had Bone Metastasis (Metastasis is a variable in this dataset). I now need to find the corresponding patient IDs for the output I was given.

Code:

```r
pattern_matches <- grep(pattern = "Bone", 
        x = brcaClin$Metastatic.Site, value = TRUE)
head(pattern_matches)
table(pattern_matches)
```

Output:

```
Bone                     Bone|Liver                Lung|Bone|Liver 
                             9                              2                              1 
Lung|Bone|Liver|Other, specify 
                             1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wildcards for filter function in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47609373/wildcards-for-filter-function-in-dplyr)

Answer (score 1):

Leaving out `value = TRUE` will give you the matching indices.

```r
inds <- grep(pattern = "Bone", 
        x = brcaClin$Metastatic.Site)
brcaClin$ID[inds]
```

(assuming that `ID` is a variable in your data set that contains patient IDs).